# Add new object to array in nested JSON document

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Disclaimer: C# isn't really my forte, guys; I'm usually a database guy. Alot of this is pieced together code I've found here and there; so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a new object to an existing JSON document that a user opens and then saving the updates to that file. The below is a made up JSON that follows the same basic structure and I want to be able to add a new "car" to a "person".  The "new" values are coming via textboxes and dropdowns.

```
{
  "Name": "Bob Bob",
  "City": "Louisville",
  "State": "Kentucky",
  "Address": "123 City Ln",
  "Cars": [
    {
      "Make": "Ford",
      "Model": "Explorer",
      "Color": "White"
    },
    {
      "Make": "Dodge",
      "Model": "Caravan",
      "Color": "White"
    },
    {
      "Make": "Bat",
      "Model": "Mobile",
      "Color": "Black:"
    }
  ],
  "Jobs": [
    {
      "Employer": "Walmart",
      "Position": "Greeter",
      "Pay": "$35,000",
      "EndDate": "12/25/1999"
    },
    {
      "Employer": "Target",
      "Position": "Cashier",
      "Pay": "$32,000",
      "EndDate": "1/1/2002"
    },
    {
      "Employer": "SkyNet",
      "Position": "Programmer",
      "Pay": "$86,000",
      "EndDate": "5/8/2023"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the below classes set up

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set;}
    public string State { get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public Cars[] Cars {get; set;}
    public Jobs[] Jobs {get; set;}
}

public class Cars
{
    public string Make { get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set;}
    public string Color { get; set;}
}

public class Jobs
{
    public string Employer { get; set;}
    public string Position { get; set;}
    public string Pay { get; set;}
    public string EndDate { get; set;}
}
```

Here's the code I have so far

```
private void btnSaveUpdates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Make = cbMake.Text;
    string Model = txtModel.Text;
    string Color = cbColor.Text;
    string filePath = txtFileLoc.Text;

    DoJSONWork(filePath, Make, Model, Color);
}

public static void DoJSONWork(string filePath, string Make, string Model, string Color)
{
    var FileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileStream))
    {
        using (JsonTextReader JSONreader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                JSONreader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                while (JSONreader.Read())
                {
                    if (JSONreader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                    {
                        Person p = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(JSONreader);

                        Cars cars = p.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Make + c.Model + c.Color == Make + Model + Color);
                        if (cars == null)
                        {
                            cars = new Cars
                            {
                                Make = Make,
                                Model = Model,
                                Color = Color
                            };
                            p.Cars = p.Cars.Concat(new Cars[]
                            {
                              cars
                            }).ToArray();

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //I honestly don't know what to do next 
    }
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to update the "cars" in the JSON document. Do I need to deserialize and serialize the entire JSON doc?

Comment: Have you considered using JSON-Patch instead? It's a scheme where you describe the changes to make to a JSON document, and the engine handles the actual work for you

Comment: `p.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Make + c.Model + c.Color == Make + Model + Color);` <-- Doing this is very inefficient because it's going to concatenate (and allocate and copy) those things together for _every_ comparison - instead just compare the strings directly (`c.Make.Equals( make ) && c.Model.Equals( model ) && etc` without creating new temporary strings (and I hope that isn't a habit you've picked-up from SQL, because doing that in SQL will make queries non-SARGable).

Comment: @Dai I haven't tried JSON-Patch I'll have to look into it; thanks for that.  regarding the concat. No, that's not something I picket up from SQL. I actually brain-farted on how to compare to ensure the same car object doesn't already exist in the JSON doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need any classes, just parse your json

```
    var json =File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var cars = (JArray)jObj["Cars"];
    
    if (cars == null) cars = new JArray();
    else if (cars.Any(c => ((string)c["Make"]) == Make
                                && ((string)c["Model"]) == Model
                                 && ((string)c["Color"]) == Color)) 
                                return;
    cars.Add(new JObject
    {

        ["Make"] = Make,
        ["Model"] = Model,
        ["Color"] = Color
    });
    
    json=jObj.ToString();
    
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
```

or you can use Cars class, since you have it already

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    List<Cars> cars = jObj["Cars"].ToObject<List<Cars>>();

    if (cars.Any(c => c.Make + c.Model + c.Color == Make + Model + Color)) return;

    cars.Add(new Cars
    {
        Make = Make,
        Model = Model,
        Color = Color
    });

    jObj["Cars"] = JArray.FromObject(cars);

    json = jObj.ToString();
```

Comment: While strictly speaking it may not be necessary to have specific classes, it's surely encouraged to create them. Especially if it's not only a single use script ... It makes your code better readable, better maintainable and more robust ...

Comment: @Dai Yes, I agree with you about more robust code,  but we loose significantly in performance, since it is using reflections to create c# objects.  The code should be just tested very well since we are not using typed objects.

Comment: @derpirscher I'm going to strongly disagree with that because manipulating a JSON document at the structural level is the best way to preserve all data in the file - whereas going through deserialization+reserialization will likely lead to dropped comments, file reformatting, and if you're not careful: added JSON properties that don't correspond to concrete class properties will be silently-dropped (!!!) by most JSON libs I've worked with - fortunately with Newtonsoft.Json there's the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute to preserve "new" properties but I've used plenty of JSON libs that lost data

Comment: @Dai That depends on the usecase. But from the description in the current question, the JSON seems to be some sort of a data storage and any app manipulating that storage should be aware of the datamodel. I stand with my opionion: Manipulation on the document level itself are ok, if it's just a one-time job or an aribtrary document. If it's sort of a data-storage, the application should be aware of the whole model ...

Comment: unfortunately, I can't add anything to the discussion above.  Specifically speaking to the question and the intended result; this answers the need.

Answer (score -1):

the short answer is Yes.
in order to manipulate a json first you should Deserialize it to a Collection of a type that c# understands after you can add data to the collection and then serialize it again the code goes something like this

`var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(myJsonString);`

then you can find or add an object to the list

`list.Add(new Person());`

and in the end, you must convert your list to json

`var convertedToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);`

by the way `JsonConvert` is in the namespace of `using Newtonsoft.Json;`
there are plenty of ways to convert.
this package is one of the easy ones

Comment: _"the short answer is Yes. in order to manipulate a json first you should Deserialize it to a Collection"_ - that isn't necessary at all: there are plenty of APIs for manipulating JSON at the token level or grammar level without needing to serialization, such as Newtonsoft.Json's own `JToken` type which supports mutable JSON documents.